# best way to load big model in ThreeJs And how to Release the cache in ThreeJs

Tags: three.js, load, browser-cache

question 1: 
In My Application  I used  JsonLoader to load my model about 65MB with .js format, it's takes 10 second . it's too long for us. does any way to load big models? or any better loader or better format?

question 2:
it's about threeJs,In my case,  i uesed remove() function to remove model from scene,but the cache doesn't release  immediately in browser ,it's takes  more than 20 second to be free; how could i do ? this is my code:  this.scene.remove(i);  i is my model.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a very heavy format. Try using [OBJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) or [glTF](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF). THREE.js has loaders for each of them in its examples.

Regarding memory release, this is inherent to JavaScript, which uses garbage collection to release memory. (Here's an [MDN article on JavaScript memory management](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management).) Just like Java, this happens "once in a while," so you just have to wait for it to happen.

Answer (score 0):

**Q1:** [OpenCTM](http://openctm.sourceforge.net/) is also a good compression format, but is, however, limited to single triangle meshes. So, you can't store whole scenes with it. But it is also possible to choose a lossy compression which results in a very high compression rate. There are also examples for three.js: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_ctm

**Q2:**
If you want to really remove your model, you need to call `dispose()` on the geometry object to remove the object from memory (materials and textures also have a `dispose` method).

Docs are saying: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/BufferGeometry

> .dispose ()
>
> Disposes the object from memory.
>  
>   You need to call this when you want the bufferGeometry removed while the application is running.

Comment: remember to clear all the textures and materials with `dispose` also :)